# What replaces TermsExecution.And in NEST 2.3.3 (upgrading from NEST 1.6.2)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

We are in the process of upgrading ElasticSearch and NEST from 1.6.2 -> 2.3.3.

What replaces how we do `TermsExecution.And` in 2.3.3?

How can this be easily done with an unknown number of terms that need to match? e.g. before you were able to just pass in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TermsExecution.And` on a `terms` query should be converted to a `bool` query with a conjunction of `must` (or `filter`, depending on query/filter context) queries, with each query being a `term` query on an individual value.

For example,

```
client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Query(q => +q
        .Term("field", "value1")
        && +q
        .Term("field", "value2")
    )
);
```

yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": {
              "value": "value1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "field": {
              "value": "value2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```